# does anyone know of lightboxes or image zoomers which are compatible with SCP?

Tags: extensions, configurable-product

SCP,([Simple Configurable Product](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple)), is a very popular extension for configurable products in magento. However, when attempting to change the image in response to configurable options chosen it seems to break as it was only designed to work with the default Magento image zoomer.

Searches on Google reveal that dozens and dozens of people have the same issue. The community would really benefit from a basic list of compatible lightboxes or image zoomers (other than the default).

Does anyone know of a compantible one (or, at least, instructions of how to make one compatible)?

Comment: Why do you want another zoomer?

Comment: I really do not like the default zoomer, but I really need SCP.

Comment: I meant it more technical.

Comment: do you mean - why can I not just change the code of the default zoomer to one of my choosing'?

Comment: technically, there is nothing wrong with the default zoomer, I only dislike aesthetically. I would like a zoomer more like Cloudzoom (where hovering over the picture reveals a magnified version to its side).

Comment: I'm no frontend developer but I would say this should be no problem with CSS?

Comment: were you able to get any information on this one as I also want to use SCP and Lightbox.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a lightbox extension that works well with SCP - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ag-cloud-roll-over-to-zoom.html
However, for all of these extensions it is necessary to deal a little bit with the javascript initialization code for the zoomer and the classes and IDs of the divs it affects.

Comment: could you share your edits to have both extensions working nicely together? , i use scp too & this zoom extension. did some tries without success (editing Product.Config.prototype.showFullImageDiv)